How to reset committed file permission changes (mode change)?
I changed the permissions of all my files and directories of my git repository and committed it to my main branch, eg.
mode change 100755 => 100644 path/to/file.sh

I wanted to reset now these changes and used git reset --hard HEAD~1, but the file permissions are still the same.
I tried to checkout another branch without those file permission changes, but the file permissions are still the same.
I tried the snippet I found in the web
git diff -p -R --no-ext-diff --no-color --diff-filter=M |  \
grep -E "^(diff|(old|new) mode)" --color=never |           \
git apply

but getting this error: error: No valid patches in input (allow with "--allow-empty").
How can I reset those "mode change" file permission changes to the permissions as they were in HEAD~1?
Will it work when I force push another non-updated version of my main branch?

Are you on Windows?

No, MacOS and RHEL. I changed the file permissions on RHEL, but my main coding environment is MacOS.


error: No valid patches in input (allow with "--allow-empty")


You get this error since you did executed git add to your files which means that there are no changes made.
The snippet you found is working on commited changes which you don't have yet.


Check the demo below to see its working
The second demo will reproduce your error.

The answer which is posted here:
How to restore the permissions of files and directories within git if they have been modified?
Is working as expected:

Note

There is one change as you can see in the demo
When trying to reset some of the files got w permissions which were not there in the origin commit.


#!/bin/bash

# Clone the original repo
cd        /tmp
rm -rf    /tmp/local-repo
git init  /tmp/local-repo

# Switch to the new repo
cd /tmp/local-repo

# Set permissions to file
for i in {4..7};
do 
  echo $i > $i.txt 
  chmod $i$i$i $i.txt
done  

# Commit the changes
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"

# View current permissions
echo -e "----------------------------------------------------------------"
echo -e "Initial permissions"
echo -e ""
ls -la

# Now lets change the permissions of the files
chmod 777 *.txt

# View current permissions
echo -e ""
echo -e "----------------------------------------------------------------"
echo -e "Updated permissions"
echo -e ""
ls -la

# revert prevoius permissions
echo -e ""
echo -e "----------------------------------------------------------------"
echo -e "Reverted permissions"
echo -e ""

git diff -p -R --no-ext-diff --no-color --diff-filter=M \
    | grep -E "^(diff|(old|new) mode)" --color=never    \
    | git apply

# View current permissions
ls -la

Output:
Initialized empty Git repository in /private/tmp/local-repo/.git/
[main (root-commit) d29864b] Initial commit
 4 files changed, 4 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 4.txt
 create mode 100755 5.txt
 create mode 100644 6.txt
 create mode 100755 7.txt
----------------------------------------------------------------
Initial permissions

total 32
drwxr-xr-x   7 nirg  wheel  224 Apr 27 00:35 .
drwxrwxrwt  12 root  wheel  384 Apr 27 00:35 ..
drwxr-xr-x  14 nirg  wheel  448 Apr 27 00:35 .git
-r--r--r--   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:35 4.txt
-r-xr-xr-x   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:35 5.txt
-rw-rw-rw-   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:35 6.txt
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:35 7.txt

----------------------------------------------------------------
Updated permissions

total 32
drwxr-xr-x   7 nirg  wheel  224 Apr 27 00:35 .
drwxrwxrwt  12 root  wheel  384 Apr 27 00:35 ..
drwxr-xr-x  14 nirg  wheel  448 Apr 27 00:35 .git
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:35 4.txt
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:35 5.txt
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:35 6.txt
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:35 7.txt

----------------------------------------------------------------
Reverted permissions

total 32
drwxr-xr-x   7 nirg  wheel  224 Apr 27 00:35 .
drwxrwxrwt  12 root  wheel  384 Apr 27 00:35 ..
drwxr-xr-x  14 nirg  wheel  448 Apr 27 00:35 .git
-rw-r--r--   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:35 4.txt
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:35 5.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:35 6.txt
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:35 7.txt

# Original start
-r--r--r--   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:35 4.txt
-r-xr-xr-x   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:35 5.txt

# After "recover"
# Extra "w"
-rw-r--r--   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:35 4.txt
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:35 5.txt

2. Reproduce your error

Setting files to permissions like 000,001 etc does not allow to add the files to git, git add will fail and the result will be the error you got.
Since no files were added to git this is the error when you try to run the snippet

error: No valid patches in input (allow with "--allow-empty")

## Set the permissions form 000-777
Initialized empty Git repository in /private/tmp/local-repo/.git/
error: open("0.txt"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file '0.txt'
fatal: adding files failed
On branch main

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        0.txt
        1.txt
        2.txt
        3.txt
        4.txt
        5.txt
        6.txt
        7.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
----------------------------------------------------------------
Initial permissions

total 64
drwxr-xr-x  11 nirg  wheel  352 Apr 27 00:32 .
drwxrwxrwt  12 root  wheel  384 Apr 27 00:32 ..
drwxr-xr-x  11 nirg  wheel  352 Apr 27 00:32 .git
----------   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:32 0.txt
---x--x--x   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:32 1.txt
--w--w--w-   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:32 2.txt
--wx-wx-wx   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:32 3.txt
-r--r--r--   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:32 4.txt
-r-xr-xr-x   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:32 5.txt
-rw-rw-rw-   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:32 6.txt
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:32 7.txt

----------------------------------------------------------------
Updated permissions

total 64
drwxr-xr-x  11 nirg  wheel  352 Apr 27 00:32 .
drwxrwxrwt  12 root  wheel  384 Apr 27 00:32 ..
drwxr-xr-x  11 nirg  wheel  352 Apr 27 00:32 .git
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:32 0.txt
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:32 1.txt
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:32 2.txt
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:32 3.txt
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:32 4.txt
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:32 5.txt
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:32 6.txt
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nirg  wheel    2 Apr 27 00:32 7.txt

----------------------------------------------------------------
Reverted permissions

error: No valid patches in input (allow with "--allow-empty")

